# How to pass variable in angular Pipe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, typescript

I need to show some definite number of decimal digit in my output [length of decimal digit is returned by stored procedure] and length of these decimal digits vary.However I do not need to care integer part it just decimal I have to worry about.Hence I used number pipe. This works fine till I pass hard coded value like this:

```
{{transaction.Rate| number :'.2-3'}}
```

It shows expected value: `713.753 [I do not care integer part]`

However I have a field in transaction model called `RateDecimal`. I want to pass this field instead of '3' in above snippet.

```
{{transaction.Rate | number :'.2-`transaction.RateDecimal`'}}
```

It throws error.
How to pass the same?Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am adding my working example here:

```
{{transaction.ExchangeRate | number : '.2-' + transaction.CustomerRateDecimal}}
```

The above thing works for me as number pipe expects values in quotes for decimal part hence concatenate is playing good here.

Comment: The standard number filter wants a numeric parameter

Comment: It takes a string as well as long as it is a valid number.

Comment: but '.2-' concatenated to a string is not a valid number.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I just reread the question. I'm not sure why I thought adding a hyphen in a number would be valid.

Comment: @dkaramazov: In fact your earlier suggestion worked as I think I am looking only after decimal digit hence it has to be concatanated with decimal string .Let me know your thought.Sorry for posting too early.

Comment: I'll add my code back the way it was, but I'm not sure that it works as you describe. Could you add some more clarification to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `{{transaction.Rate | number:transaction.RateDecimal}}`

Comment: Yes that works .I missed to state in my question that I needed minimum number of decimal digit too.

Comment: Perhaps `{{transaction.Rate | number:Math.min(transaction.RateDecimal,2)}}` but I'm not sure if it will be able to call the min function in that expression. You might have to implement your own custom filter.

Comment: Ohh looks like I was too early to say , it breaks if I just provide `{{transaction.Rate | number:transaction.RateDecimal}}` .However this worked: `number :'.1-'+ transaction.CustomerRateDecimal'